# How to set "no-store" into the response header?

Tags: cherrypy

I have set in my cherrypy configuration file:

```
'tools.expires.on': True,
'tools.expires.secs': 0,
'tools.expires.force': True
```

This gives me a reponse header like this:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
```

How to add "no-store" into the final reponse header? The official documentation doesn't talk about this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a month, but saw your question and thought I would take a crack at it if you have not already solved this.

Try setting the cache-control in the response header before your return block within your function.

From [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) and [this](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/3.3.0/progguide/customheaders.html)

```
#python
import cherrypy

def multi_headers():
    cherrypy.response.header_list.extend(
        cherrypy.response.headers.encode_header_items(
            cherrypy.response.multiheaders))

cherrypy.tools.multiheaders = cherrypy.Tool('on_end_resource', multi_headers)

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.multiheaders()
    def index(self):
        cherrypy.response.multiheaders = [('Cache-Control', 'no-store')]
        return "Hello"

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

Comment: Thanks. Why can't we just set `response.headers` on `_cp_config`?

Comment: You could do that too if you wanted all of your requests within a given class to return with those headers. I *think* setting it within the function ensures only that function returns with those headers